# Crypto-Riddle: dce,/hcv uc

Tags: riddle, cipher

Here is a simple cryptogram riddle which can be deciphered without any software/assistance:

> N.m msc uc b. aysxcvo
>
> Alxans /msh,yg un tmbb.yso
>
> >./si ,bs ,yrcvbcd!

Answer how you decoded it, and the answer to the riddle!

(Hopefully I don't have any errors in it as this is my first cryptogram)

Comment: It could be an SMS that my little cousin used to send me. kthxbye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy.

> You use me to answer.
>  always pushing my buttons.
>  oops, its inverted!

How it works:

> On a QWERTY keyboard, if the key is on the top row, switch it to the bottom row, and vice versa, keeping the column intact. Middle row remains unaffected.

Oh, and the title says

> decipher me

And the solution?

> kcnt.avd

Comment: It was easy indeed! But you still have to answer the riddle :)

Comment: You missed the comma in the last line!